# duplicate definitions with name `is_soa`

Tags: rust

My code was fine last week. And out of nowhere today, this error suddenly appeared:

```
error[E0592]: duplicate definitions with name `is_soa`
   --> /.../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/trust-dns-proto-0.22.0/src/rr/record_data.rs:55:17
    |
55  | #[derive(Debug, EnumAsInner, PartialEq, Clone, Eq)]
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ duplicate definitions for `is_soa`
...
994 |     pub fn is_soa(&self) -> bool {
    |     ---------------------------- other definition for `is_soa`
```

I'm using: `rustc 1.68.0-nightly (bdb07a8ec 2022-12-11)`.
I upgraded to the latest nightly version: `rustc 1.72.0-nightly (1c53407e8 2023-05-28)`.
But the error seems to be the same. Has someone else experience this, too?

Comment: Using nightly toolchains is not a good idea if you wish to ensure stability. Regardless, we cannot identify what happened here without a proper [mre].

Comment: The tag [tag:cargo] is about some java tool, not applicable here, please read the tag descriptions before tagging.

Comment: @cafce25 sorry, removing cargo in the tags.

Comment: @Enet4 this is happening with the stable, as of today, toolchain as well. That error message is nearly stating how to get more details IF you are on nightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, alright, this was [raised in github](https://github.com/bluejekyll/trust-dns/issues/1946).

Sorry folks.

Comment: Appreciate the link. Google had indexed your SO question, but not GitHub yet.